# what is the sentence pattern in following sentence, specificcally what is the function of 'consistent with'?

Tags: phrases, adjectives, collocation

**Consistent with** maximizing the impact of rewards, managers should look for ways to increase their visibility.

Comment: What does a dictionary tell you about the meaning of "consistent with"?

Answer (score 1):

"Consistent with maximizing the impact of rewards, managers should look for ways to increase their visibility."

'Consistent' is an adjective, here meaning 'compatible', and the entire phrase before 'managers' is a **parenthetical phrase**, of the type called a *free modifier*.